# How to use a variable from def

Tags: python, function

Example

```
    G1 = 500
    G2 = 400
    avg1 = 25
    avg2 = 20

    def produce(x):
        production_time = Gx /avgx
        return production_time

    print (produce(1))
    #out: 20
```

What I want to do is combine the G and the x so that I can use my variable G1 on top.

Comment: What is the meaning of `combine the G and the x`?

Comment: Why don't you just pass `G1` into `produce` instead of doing weird dynamic variable stuff?

Comment: I'm guessing that you're thinking of having several "G-variables" (e.g. G1, G2 etc.) and depending on the int value passed to produce (x), you want to pick Gx. So "produce(3)" would result in "production_time = G3 /25". Am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I also have a variable G2. So if I use produce(2) i can use G2.

Comment: @AdrianAntonLadia Okay, and why don't you just do `produce(G2)` instead??

Comment: @rdas I want to use the variable G1, so by inputting produce(1) it combines G and 1 together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for this:

if I understood correctly you want to access a variable with the value of x then declaring that as `Dictionary` will be best for you

```
G = { 1: 500 }
avg = 25

def produce(x):
    production_time = G[x] / avg
    return production_time
print (produce(1))
```

Comment: Small nitpick: `G` is a dictionary - not a "JSON": https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries